# Ubuntu Upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04 on Mulitple PCs

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, release-upgrade

I have around 10 PCs, they currently have Ubuntu 11.04 running. I need to upgrade the PCs from 11.04 to 12.04 without downloading all the Ubuntu Packages every time. What would be the best way to upgrade them? I do not want to loose settings and/or data on these PCs, so re-installing is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: Create a 12.04 CD or USB- Stick, boot it up and choose the upgrade option when asked.

[image]

You will not loose any settings and/or data this way.

EDIT:
It seems I didn't do my homework properly, I'm sorry. You will have to do the whole procedure twice, first by upgrading to 11.10, and then to 12.04. I wish there was a better solution (besides a fresh install), however I don't know of any.

Comment: -1
It is impossible to  upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04 directly

This upgrade is dangerous This upgrade may lose packages

Comment: I had gone through your answer but the upgrade option already disable.